# Cannot find module './installers/setupEvents' with Electron-Winstaller

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I'm attempting to package my Angular app on Windows 10, but I receive the error and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it:

[image]

I am running the command:

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . qlocktwo-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=src/assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"QlockTwo App\"",
```

### Changes made when converting to Electron

**index.html**
I changed `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`

**electron-main.js**

```
const setupEvents = require('./installers/setupEvents');
if (setupEvents.handleSquirrelEvent()) {
  return;
}

const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let win;

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
  win.loadFile('index.html');
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**installers/setupEvents.ts**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

module.exports = {
  handleSquirrelEvent: function() {
    if (process.argv.length === 1) {
      return false;
    }

    const ChildProcess = require('child_process');
    const path = require('path');

    const appFolder = path.resolve(process.execPath, '..');
    const rootAtomFolder = path.resolve(appFolder, '..');
    const updateDotExe = path.resolve(path.join(rootAtomFolder, 'Update.exe'));
    const exeName = path.basename(process.execPath);
    const spawn = function(command, args) {
      let spawnedProcess, error;

      try {
        spawnedProcess = ChildProcess.spawn(command, args, {detached: true});
      } catch (error) {}

      return spawnedProcess;
    };

    const spawnUpdate = function(args) {
      return spawn(updateDotExe, args);
    };

    const squirrelEvent = process.argv[1];
    switch (squirrelEvent) {
      case '--squirrel-install':
      case '--squirrel-updated':
        spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName]);

        setTimeout(app.quit, 1000);
        return true;

      case '--squirrel-uninstall':
        spawnUpdate(['--removeShortcut', exeName]);

        setTimeout(app.quit, 1000);
        return true;

      case '--squirrel-obsolete':
        app.quit();
        return true;
    }
  }
};
```

**installers/windows/createinstaller.js**

```
const createWindowsInstaller = require('electron-winstaller').createWindowsInstaller;
const path = require('path');

getInstallerConfig()
  .then(createWindowsInstaller)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

function getInstallerConfig () {
  console.log('creating windows installer');
  const rootPath = path.join('./');
  const outPath = path.join(rootPath, 'release-builds');

  return Promise.resolve({
    appDirectory: path.join(outPath, 'Qlocktwo-app-win32-ia32/'),
    authors: 'My Name',
    noMsi: true,
    outputDirectory: path.join(outPath, 'windows-installer'),
    exe: 'qlocktwo-app.exe',
    setupExe: 'QlockTwoApp.exe',
    setupIcon: path.join(rootPath, 'src', 'assets', 'icons', 'win', 'icon.ico')
  })
}
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I was using `electron-winstaller` before and it was so freaking annoying making sure it all worked every time but when I switched to `electron-builder` everything was so easy and everything worked. So I would suggest you move to `electron-builder` at some point

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete **node_modules** folder
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. run  `npm install`

Comment: Perhaps it is something to do with running it from Windows? I have built the Windows packager code from a Mac on a different project, and that worked. I will have to test it on my Mac when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Electron Winstaller package:

npm install --save-dev electron-winstaller

Off course, you need to install electron since you cleaned it.